# Why doesn't my legend respect the padding of the parent fieldset?

Tags: html, css

Look at this:

[image]

The `<fieldset>` has a padding of `50px` on top. `<legend>` doesn't respect this, but `<p>` does. Why is this?

Note: I'm using Bootstrap in the picture below and in my Code Pen, but the question applies regardless of whether Bootstrap is used.

---

**HTML**

```
<div class='placeholder'></div>

<fieldset>
  <legend>LEGEND</legend>
  <p>PARAGRAPH</p>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
.placeholder {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

fieldset {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwVBeW?editors=110)

Comment: my limited understanding is that `legend`s are meant to display at the border of the `fieldset` (like a title for the set) - if you need to move the set down, you may need to increase the margin of the set or if you want the legend (title) down, then apply the padding to the `legend` itself

Comment: @ochi you are correct! I gave a `hacky` answer to the doomed question :)

Comment: Why not just google it and read http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3479111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the [Rendering section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-fieldset-and-legend-elements) of the HTML5 spec says so

> **10.3.13 The [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-fieldset-element) and [`legend`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-legend-element) elements**
>
> If the [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-fieldset-element) element has a child that matches the conditions
>   in the list below, then the first such child is the [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-fieldset-element)
>   element's **rendered legend**:
>
> - The child is a [`legend`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-legend-element) element.
> - The child is not out-of-flow (e.g. not absolutely positioned or floated).
> - The child is generating a box (e.g. it is not 'display:none').
>
> A [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-fieldset-element) element's [rendered legend](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendered-legend), if any, is expected
>   to be rendered over the top border edge of the [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-fieldset-element) element
>   as a 'block' box (overriding any explicit 'display' value).

Answer (score 0):

Filedset and legend work together and p acts as its own entity this is why legend does not respect the padding. Legend is within the fieldset. If you want to have the legend below fieldset, then you can use the css:

```
fieldset, legend {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```